# Can I modify this waypoint so that it doesnt take effect until scrolling 500px down the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

A WordPress theme I am using has this code which is what I assume initiates the themes fixed header class once the user starts to scroll down.

Is there a way to modify this so that the class is not initiated on scroll rather initiated when the user gets to a certain point down the screen such as 100px or something liek that. Here is the code.

```
                if ( et_is_fixed_nav ) {
                $('#main-content').waypoint( {
                    offset: function() {
                        if ( etRecalculateOffset ) {
                            et_calculate_header_values();
                            etRecalculateOffset = false;
                        }
                        return et_header_offset;
                    },
                    handler : function( direction ) {
                        if ( direction === 'down' ) {
                            $('#main-header').addClass( 'et-fixed-header' );
                        } else {
                            $('#main-header').removeClass( 'et-fixed-header' );
                        }
                    }
                } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help Austin. You were right about it being handled elsewhere. With the help f a friend, I found this bit elsewhere in the file...

```
        function et_calculate_header_values() {
        var $top_header = $( '#top-header' ),
            secondary_nav_height = $top_header.length && $top_header.is( ':visible' ) ? $top_header.innerHeight() : 0,
            admin_bar_height     = $( '#wpadminbar' ).length ? $( '#wpadminbar' ).innerHeight() : 0;

        et_header_height      = $( '#main-header' ).innerHeight() + secondary_nav_height - 1,
        et_header_modifier    = et_header_height <= 90 ? et_header_height - 29 : et_header_height - 56,
        et_header_offset      = et_header_modifier + admin_bar_height;

        et_primary_header_top = secondary_nav_height + admin_bar_height;
    }

    function et_fix_slider_height() {
        if ( ! $et_pb_slider.length ) return;

        $et_pb_slider.each( function() {
            var $slide = $(this).find( '.et_pb_slide' ),
                $slide_container = $slide.find( '.et_pb_container' ),
                max_height = 0;

            $slide_container.css( 'min-height', 0 );

            $slide.each( function() {
                var $this_el = $(this),
                    height = $this_el.innerHeight();

                if ( max_height < height )
                    max_height = height;
            } );
```

And then I changed this line...

```
et_header_offset      = et_header_modifier + admin_bar_height;
```

to this...

```
et_header_offset      = et_header_modifier + admin_bar_height - 1000;
```

Mission accomplished. Thanks for your help austinthedeveloper and Dan Mossop. By the way, this is what is being used in the custom.js in the Divi theme by Elegant Themes just in case in helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your theme is using [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/). The link I attached shows how to adjust the offset. The function that is currently in place looks like it handles the offset somewhere else though, possibly in your Wordpress options panel. I haven't tested it but I'd imagine your code would end up looking like this:

```
            $('#main-content').waypoint( {
                offset: 100px,
                handler : function( direction ) {
                    if ( direction === 'down' ) {
                        $('#main-header').addClass( 'et-fixed-header' );
                    } else {
                        $('#main-header').removeClass( 'et-fixed-header' );
                    }
                }
            } );
```

Comment: Thanks austinthedeveloper. Your explanation helped me to understand the problem. You were correct in assuming the offset was being handled elswhere. I found it and was able to resolve the issue with a little help from others as well. Thanks!